# VkApiLink приходит к своим и другим статьям

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

здраствуйте! VkApiLink приходит к своим и другим статьям.. Кароче когда она отображается в какой либо статье, то она потом на другие начинает напрыгивать, через 1-5 статей... как исправить неподскажите?

```
    public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private int mShowStyle;
        private int musicShowStyle;
        VKPostArray obj;
        VKApiPhoto vkPhoto;
        ArrayList<String> imgUrls1;
        VKApiUser mainUser;
        Context ctx;

    public PostAdapter(Context context, VKPostArray posts, VKApiUser user) {
            super();
            this.obj = posts;
            this.mainUser = user;
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            ctx = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final PostViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            final VKApiPost p = obj.get(position);

    VKAttachments att = new VKAttachments();
            att = p.attachments;

for (VKAttachments.VKApiAttachment attachment : p.attachments) {
    Log.d("TAG", "attachment getType " + attachment.getType());
    switch (attachment.getType()){
        case AUDIO:
            if (attachment.getType().equals(AUDIO)){
                VKApiAudio audio = (VKApiAudio) att.get(0);
                Log.d("TAG", "audio title: " + audio.title);
                if (audio != null){
                    holder.layone4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.as1.setText(audio.artist);
                    holder.as2.setText(audio.title);
                    //Picasso.with(ctx).load(link.image_src).into(holder.i1);
                } else {
                    holder.layone4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.as1.setText(null);
                    holder.as2.setText(null);
                    //holder.i1.setImageDrawable(null);
                }}
            break;
        case VIDEO:
            if (attachment.getType().equals(VIDEO)){
                VKApiVideo video = (VKApiVideo) att.get(0);
                Log.d("TAG", "video title: " + video.title);
                if (video != null){
                    holder.layone3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.vs1.setText(video.title);
                    holder.vs2.setText(video.description);
                    //Picasso.with(ctx).load(link.image_src).into(holder.i1);
                } else {
                    holder.layone3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.vs1.setText(null);
                    holder.vs2.setText(null);
                    //holder.i1.setImageDrawable(null);
                }}
            break;
        case DOCUMENTS:
            if (attachment.getType().equals(DOCUMENTS)){
                VKApiDocument document = (VKApiDocument) att.get(0);
                Log.d("TAG", "document title: " + document.title);
                if (document != null){
                    holder.layone5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.ds1.setText(document.title);
                    holder.ds2.setText(document.size + " мб");
                    //Picasso.with(ctx).load(link.image_src).into(holder.i1);
                } else {
                    holder.layone5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.ds1.setText(null);
                    holder.ds2.setText(null);
                    //holder.i1.setImageDrawable(null);
                }}
            break;
        case LINK:
            if (attachment.getType().equals(LINK)){
                VKApiLink link = (VKApiLink) att.get(0);
                Log.d("TAG", "link description: " + link.description);
                if (att.get(0).getType().equals(LINK)){
                    holder.layone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.s1.setText(link.title);
                    holder.s2.setText(link.url);
                    Picasso.with(ctx).load(link.image_src).into(holder.i1);
                } else {
                    holder.layone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.s1.setText(null);
                    holder.s2.setText(null);
                    holder.i1.setImageDrawable(null);
                    Log.d("TAG", "link description gone: " + link.description);
                }}else {

            }
            break;
        case POOL:
            if (attachment.getType().equals(POOL)){
                VKApiPoll poll = (VKApiPoll) att.get(0);
                Log.d("TAG", "pool question: " + poll.question);
                if (poll != null){
                holder.layone2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //holder.pps1.setText(poll.getType());
                holder.pps2.setText(poll.question);
            } else {
                    holder.layone2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //holder.pps1.setText(null);
                    holder.pps2.setText(null);
                }}
            break;
        case ALBUM:
            if (attachment.getType().equals(ALBUM)){
                VKApiPhotoAlbum photoAlbum = (VKApiPhotoAlbum) att.get(0);
                Log.d("TAG", "photoAlbum title: " + photoAlbum.title);
                if(photoAlbum != null) {
                    holder.layone1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.ps1.setText(photoAlbum.title);
                    holder.ps2.setText("В альбоме " + photoAlbum.size + " фотографий");
                } else {
                    holder.layone1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.ps1.setText(null);
                    holder.ps2.setText(null);
                }}
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
        }

            holder.textPost.setText(p.text);
            Linkify.addLinks(holder.textPost, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

     int i;
            imgUrls1 = new ArrayList<>(att.size());

            try {
                for (i = 0; i <= att.size(); i++) {
                    vkPhoto = (VKApiPhoto) att.get(i);
                    imgUrls1.add(vkPhoto.photo_807);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                holder.mNglContent.setImagesData(imgUrls1);
            }
        }
     @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return obj.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return PHOTO;
        }

    @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            switch (viewType){
                case PHOTO:
                    if (mShowStyle == NineGridImageView.STYLE_FILL) {
                        return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false));
                    } else {
                        return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false));
                    }
                case MUSIC:
                    if (musicShowStyle == audio.getType().length()) {
                        return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.musicitem, parent, false));
                    }}
            return null;
        }

    public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            CardView cv;
        TextView textPost, news_name, textDatePost, textrepostPost, textlikePost;
        ImageView  like, repost,i1, ppi1, pi1;
        CircleImageView news_ava;
        CheckBox like1;
        NineGridImageView mNglContent;

        ImageView playMusic;
        TextView artistMusic, titleMusic, durationMusic, urlMusic;

        TextView s1, s2;
        TextView ps1, ps2, pps1, pps2, as1, as2, vs1, vs2, ds1, ds2;
        LinearLayout layone, layone1, layone2, layone3, layone4, layone5;

                private NineGridImageViewAdapter<String> mAdapter = new NineGridImageViewAdapter<String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onDisplayImage(Context context, ImageView imageView, String s) {
                        if(imageView == null){
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_ab_app);
                        }else{
                            Picasso.with(context).load(s).into(imageView);
                    }}

                    @Override
                    protected ImageView generateImageView(Context context) {
                        return super.generateImageView(context);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onItemImageClick(Context context, int position, List<String> list) {

                    }
                };

                public PostViewHolder(View v) {
                    super(v);
                    cv = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view_wall);

                news_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.news_name);
                news_ava = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.news_ava);
                textDatePost = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textDatePost);

                textPost = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textPost);

                like = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_like_button);
                textlikePost = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_likes_count);

                //like1 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_like_button);
                textrepostPost = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_reposts_count);
                repost = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_repost);

                mNglContent = (NineGridImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ngl_images);
                mNglContent.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                playMusic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.playMusic);
                artistMusic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.artistMusic);
                titleMusic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.albumMusic);
                durationMusic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.durationMusic);
                //urlMusic = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.urlMusic);

                layone = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.link);
                layone1 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.photoAlbum);
                layone2 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.pool);
                layone3 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.video);
                layone4 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.audio);
                layone5 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.document);

                as1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.as1);
                as2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.as2);
                //ai1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.i1);

                vs1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vs1);
                vs2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vs2);
                //ai1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.i1);

                ds1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ds1);
                ds2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ds2);
                //ai1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.i1);

                s1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.s1);
                s2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.s2);
                i1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.i1);

                pi1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.pi1);
                ps1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ps1);
                ps2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ps2);

                ppi1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ppi1);
                pps1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pps1);
                pps2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pps2);
                }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас пустой else в котором вам надо отобразить состояние при отсутствии ссылки. Заполните его кодом убирающим картинку, тест и прочее примерно так:

```
if(link != null) {
    holder.layone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.s1.setText(link.title);
    holder.s2.setText(link.url);
    Picasso.with(ctx).load(link.image_src).into(holder.i1);
}else{
    holder.layone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.s1.setText(null);
    holder.s2.setText(null);
    holder.i1.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

Comment: Я пробывал уже так...не помогает(((

Comment: @sviter-pro, а если в логи вывести аттачи - что показывает?

Comment: Log.d("TAG", "att type" + attachment.getType()); добавил перед switch..... все выводит без вопросов...

Comment: Добавил логирование в if(link!=null) и еlse так вот в else не срабатыает

Comment: Видимо он у вас всегда не нулл. Проверяйте его тип а не наличие

Comment: If(link.getType!=null)   тоже не помогает((((

Comment: link.getType().equals("link")

Comment: Непомогло..блин вот гемор((((

Comment: att.get(0).getType().equals("link")

Comment: Не помогло...Статью обновил...Работаю пока только с LINK/Посмотрите может я где ошибся?

Comment: У вас переуслржнена логика. Ошибка в том, что для постов без ссылок в case нет вхождения и нет очистки данных при переиспользовании разметки

Comment: Так мне надо добавить щас POST в case  и все перекинуть в него?

Comment: Долго описывать. Вкратце - убрать свитч, проверять если в аттачах ссылка и обрабатывать это

Comment: обязательно займусь...скажите а как вызвать VkApiPool, а то он не отбражается как все?